# How to pass arguments to function using eventlisteners?

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I am building a flashcard game where the user would select the animal group, then a random animal from that group would pop up on screen.

However, the same value appears regardless of what value is passed to the function   `displayAnimal(datavalue)`

**Here is the troublesome part:**

```
var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("row")
for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
  var datavalue;
  datavalue = classname[i].getAttribute("data-animal-cat");
  classname[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    displayAnimal(datavalue);
  });
}
```

**Here is the full code:**

```js
var birdArray = ["Owl", "Hummingbird", "Toucan"]
var dogArray = ["Bulldog", "Dash Hound", "German Shepard"]
var fishArray = ["Goldfish", "Mahi Mahi", "Catfish"]
var randomBird = birdArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * birdArray.length)];
var randomDog = dogArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * dogArray.length)];
var randomFish = fishArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * fishArray.length)];

function initFlashCardGame() {
    var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("row")
    for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
      var datavalue;
      datavalue = classname[i].getAttribute("data-animal-cat");
      classname[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        displayAnimal(datavalue);
      });
    }

    function displayAnimal(datavalue) {
      var animalType;
      if (datavalue === "birds") {
        alert(randomBird);
      } else if (datavalue = "dogs") {
        alert(randomDog);
      } else if (datavalue = "fish") {
        alert(randomFish);
      }
    }
  }
  //add event listener when window loads        
window.addEventListener("load", initFlashCardGame);
```

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 480px;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: arial;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
.row {
  background: #116995;
  pading: 20px;
  margin: 6px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
}
.row:hover {
  background: yellow;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 25px;
}
p {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p>SELECT ANIMAL GROUP</p>
  <div class="row" data-animal-cat="birds">
    Birds
  </div>
  <div class="row" data-animal-cat="birds">
    Dogs
  </div>
  <div class="row" data-animal-cat="birds">
    Fish
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript infamous Loop issue?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue)

Comment: All three divs have same value for `data-animal-cat`

Comment: Did you mean "pass" not "parse"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues.

1. You missed to update data attribute (`data-animal-cat`) in HTML. All 3 rows have the same value.
2. If else statement have assignment operator(`=`) instead of equality operator(`==` or `===`).
3. Pass the element on click instead of passing the data attribute.
4. Get random values on each click (i.e Initialize `randomBird` on click event)

Here is a updated code.

```js
var birdArray = ["Owl", "Hummingbird", "Toucan"]
var dogArray = ["Bulldog", "Dash Hound", "German Shepard"]
var fishArray = ["Goldfish", "Mahi Mahi", "Catfish"]

function initFlashCardGame() {
    var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("row");

    for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
      classname[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        displayAnimal(this);
      });
    }

    function displayAnimal(obj) {
      var dv = obj.getAttribute("data-animal-cat");

      if (dv == "birds") {
        var randomBird = birdArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * birdArray.length)];
        alert(randomBird);
      } else if (dv == "dogs") {
        var randomDog = dogArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * dogArray.length)];
        alert(randomDog);
      } else if (dv == "fish") {
        var randomFish = fishArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * fishArray.length)];
        alert(randomFish);
      }
    }
  }
  //add event listener when window loads        
window.addEventListener("load", initFlashCardGame);
```

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 480px;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: arial;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
.row {
  background: #116995;
  pading: 20px;
  margin: 6px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
}
.row:hover {
  background: yellow;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 25px;
}
p {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p>SELECT ANIMAL GROUP</p>
  <div class="row" data-animal-cat="birds">
    Birds
  </div>
  <div class="row" data-animal-cat="dogs">
    Dogs
  </div>
  <div class="row" data-animal-cat="fish">
    Fish
  </div>
</div>
```